# Algorithm for merging a strict JS input object into a loose template JS object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have faced a situation where I have two JavaScript objects:

Input object:

```
{
    name:"a1",
    children:[
        {name:"P", value:'newVal1'},
        {name:"Q", value:'newVal2'},
        {name:"R", value:'newVal3'},
        {name:"S1", children:[
            {name:"T", value:"newVal4"}
        ]},
    ]
}
```

Template:

```
{
  name: "a1",
  children: [
    {
      name: "b1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "c1",
          children: [
            {
              name: "P"
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "b2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "c2",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "Q"
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              name: "b3",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "R"
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              name: "b4",
              children: [
                ,
                {
                  name: "c3",
                  children: [
                    ,
                    {
                      name: "s1",
                      children: [
                        {
                          name: "e1",
                          children: [
                            {
                              name: "T"
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

I need to merge the input object into the template object such that the new values would be:

```
{
  name: "a1",
  children: [
    {
      name: "b1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "c1",
          children: [
            {
              name: "P",
              value: "newVal1",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "b2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "c2",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "Q",
                  value: "newVal2",
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              name: "b3",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "R",
                  value: "newVal3",
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              name: "b4",
              children: [
                ,
                {
                  name: "c3",
                  children: [
                    ,
                    {
                      name: "s1",
                      children: [
                        {
                          name: "e1",
                          children: [
                            {
                              name: "T",
                              value: "newVal4",
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Notice how `newVal1` etc. values have to land up  in the correct spots in the merged structure.

The intermediate layers (`a,b,c` etc.) may or may not exist, i.e. there might be many layers in-between before matching the `P Q R` layers, or on the other side, a given template object may exactly match the structure of the input, and the function/class should still be able to place values inside.

I am using Typescript, but even a JavaScript answer is welcome.

Also, does this sort of object matching have a name?

Really appreciate your time. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure that I've understood you correctly but maybe [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is what you need.

Comment: @ionut-t Object.assign() will not to merge object values with different object structures. If I merge `input` and `template` as per the question, I'd end up with the values of `P, Q` etc. in the `b1-b2-b3` layer since it copies the values residing at the same depth.